# Time created trigger doesn't get triggered. Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, triggers

I'm creating an addOn in google sheets. And I have it almost done, the only thing I need to be working is this trigger. When I click on the button of my Sidebar the trigger either gets created and then disabled or it gets created but doesn't get triggered. But when I run the code through the editor everything works normally. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

To test the trigger, I'm using this code:

Code.GS

```
let SIDEBAR_TITLE = 'Try trigger';

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() .createAddonMenu() .addItem('Try trigger', 'showSidebar') .addToUi(); 
}

function onInstall(e) { 
  onOpen(e); 
}

function showSidebar() { 
  let ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar') .evaluate() .setTitle(SIDEBAR_TITLE) .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui); 
}

function testingTrigger() { 
  let delayMinutes = 1; 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createdTrigger').timeBased().after(delayMinutes * 60 * 1000).create() 
}

function createdTrigger(){ 
 console.log('Is working...'); 
}
```

```
Sidebar.HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<!-- Required meta tags --> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div> 
    <button id="runTrigger">Try triggers</button> 
  </div>
  <script> // Add a click event listener to the button   document.getElementById("runTrigger").addEventListener("click", function() { google.script.run.testingTrigger(); // Replace with your function name }); 
  </script> 
</body>
```

With this code if I click the button of my sidebar to execute it, it gets created but never triggered. In the official code, it also gets disabled. But again, when I run it through the editor, it works normally.

So it supposed to be created (and it does), but after a minute has passed, it should execute the function "createdTrigger" and that should console "Is working". I'm just using that code to test the trigger.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is probably to have some code in `Sidebar.HTML` that creates a trigger, but the only thing within `<script>`...`</script>` tags is the *comment* that starts with `// Add a click event listener`. Insert a newline before `document.getElementById` to make the code be interpreted as code rather than as a comment.

See [JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Comments).